# inserting contents of .sty file inside latex .tex file

Tags: latex, tex

I want to know if there is a way to put the contents of a `.sty` file directly into a latex `.tex` file. I have a small number of (TeX?) macro definitions inside a file `myfile.sty` that I would prefer to just integrate into my latex file instead of keeping them in a separate package and loading them using `\usepackage{myfile}`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can simply copy the content of your `.sty` file to your document.

- Comment out anything package specific like `\ProvidesPackage{myfile}`
- if your package use `@` in macro names, you have to wrap it in  `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

%\ProvidesPackage{myfile}

\newcommand{\foo}{bar}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\foo

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` were the magic I was looking for. It turns out google searches with the @ symbol are surprisingly ineffective...